# Why is there extra margin visible despite settign it to zero

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I'm practicing some CSS,
Despite setting the margin of the H1 tag to 0,
it seems to be occupying the complete width of it's parent div, as when I insert a new element and float it to right it does not fits in the same div.
Screenshots attached for complete details.
Note: I've already set the div's width to 100px.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as the op did not set display:block explicitly. So he needs to know that a h1 has display:block by default

Comment: @TemaniAfif, In what context do you find my question to be a duplicate one, How can you assume some one to search for the topic that he's not aware of !!!

Comment: is there enough dupicates now? I can share more if you want :) .. all of them are equivalent and I also shared a link for w3schools

Comment: take your time and read my code first,
I've had already set it's width to 100px.All of your referred questions have width:100%

Answer (score 1):

H1 by default have a display:block. That makes it get width 100% if you dont specify width.
Try setting display: inline-block

Comment: Actullay, I was aware that an H1 tag is a block level element,
But I thought setting it's width explicitly would decrease it's width.
I wasn't familiar with display:inline-block property.Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

set `display: inline-block;` property on both the child elements and remove width to see if it is on the same line , then Apply Width based on your need.

Comment: Yeah it worked with applying on the first child element itself.
Thanks for the solution.